# How to set div width equal to responsive img

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to get width of img (fluid) and overlay it with `overlay-text`.
Class `overlay-text` has 100% width, but it still doesn't have equal width tothe image when the screen resolution changes.

> Is possible to set `overlay-text` width equal to img width?

**CSS**

```
.overlay-text {
    background-color: #79b13c;
    color: white;
    z-index: 50;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out, font-size 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out, font-size 0.5s;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out, font-size 0.5s;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out, font-size 0.5s;
}

.col-md-3:hover .overlay-text{
    content:"";
    background-color: #328ba6;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: ease-in-out 0.5s, font-size 0.5s;
    line-height: 2;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.col-md-3:hover .overlay-text::after{
    transition: ease-in-out 1s, font-size 1s;
}

.col-md-3 {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.col-md-3 img {
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.col-md-3:hover img{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-10%,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,-10%,0);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.overlay-text-blank {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row tiles">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
            <a href="blabla.php"><img alt="bla" src="https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1ka9bSXXXXXX0XFXXq6xXFXXXy/diamond-painting-big-size-rhinestones-embroidery-coffe-decor-decorative-coffee-beans.jpg_640x640.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                <div class="overlay-text">Cafe</div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

> **DEMO**  https://jsfiddle.net/mnmwdg4g/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

```
.overlay-text {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 33px; // the height of .overlay element
}
```

and

```
.col-md-3:hover .overlay-text{
    bottom: 48px; // the height of .overlay element when it grows
}
```

here's a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/mnmwdg4g/12/